# Samsung TV Emulator font size

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Can someone please help me with this issue. I've been banging my head to find the solution but no help...

The problem is that Samsung TV Emulator displays everything enlarged (line font-size 30ish pixels) and there does seem to have a way to override it. **This only happens within Samsung UI components.**

To make sure it wasn't something with my project I've downloaded sample project from Brightcove: [Sample project](http://opensource.brightcove.com/project/samsung-smart-tv-sample-app) but noticed the same behavior with that as well.

Here is the screenshot of my "project". It only one scene with two UI components: http://tinypic.com/r/124evqc/6

Opposed to that, here's what I see in my IDE view: http://tinypic.com/r/ezmn4l/6. As a side-note, I had to put `height: 20px` in both of my UI components' CSS in order for IDE to show them that way.

Can anyone suggest what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the button is adding 20px to its previous object, check this, maybe it helps

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea - that just might be what's going on, however, I have no clue what should I do. Should I enforce some CSS-reset rule? Or is there a way to override that 20px padding? 

This is all weird mainly because, within entire project, I did not add any padding rule. For now, I'll stay away from Samsungs UI components as it seems they are only affected...

Comment: i think you'll need to have a fix point. from this you'll need to go X pixel padding from this to next

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the TV Fonts when you installed your SDK?

From http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Sdkdownload

```
[ How to reInstall TV fonts ]
(Install TV fonts in your Windows system for compatibility with the TV)
1) Please go to this path: [SDK_INSTALL_DIR]/Emulator/Emulator2012_v3.5/bin
2) Double click each of the following files:
  - shadow_us.ttf, shadow_eu.ttf, shadow_ko.ttf, shadow_s_cn.ttf,shadow_t_cn.ttf, shadow_jp.ttf
3) Click 'install' button in the dialog box
```